# Model recognizing test dataset as one class

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I tried using transfer learning in training a model to recognize cats and dogs. The real dataset has about 25,000 training images and the test, 12,500 images.

I created directories, `train` and `test` (for my validation set) with `cats` and `dogs` subdirectories in each of them. The file names for `dogs` in the real `train` dataset is in the format, dog.1, dog.2,dog.3... while that of cat is cat.1, cat.2, cat.3... and I successfully splitted the files into the correct subdirectories

In the real test folder, the file names are just 1, 2, 3, 4...12,500 including both images of `dogs` and `cats`

I have trained my model with a validation accuracy of about 98% but when I loaded the test file for prediction, I got the output `Found 12500 images belonging to 1 classes`.  I need two classes, a `0` or a `1`.

It wasn't the case when I checked my created directories lengths. I don't know where I'm getting it wrong

all packages imported

```
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

conv_base.trainable = True

set_trainable = False
for layer in conv_base.layers:
    if layer.name == 'block5_conv1':
        set_trainable = True
    if set_trainable:
        layer.trainable = True
    else:
        layer.trainable = False


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-5),
              metrics=['acc'])




history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=320,  images
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=90)  


test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '../input/dogscatsdataset/test/',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=50,
    class_mode='binary')

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=90)
print('test acc:', test_acc)
```

output

```
Found 12500 images belonging to 1 classes.
test acc: 0.504444420337677
```

I'm new to ML and I have previously done same exercise with a model built from scratch, with same directories and test set and it worked fine. I got `Found 12500 images belonging to 2 classes` not `1 class` that I'm getting now

Answer (score 0):

According to [Keras' `flow_from_directory` documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method) about the `directory` argument:

> It should contain one subdirectory per class.

So the test files should be structured under `cats` & `dogs` subdirectories (as the training & validation data).

Keras is assuming that all images belong in one class since you didn't specify otherwise. The directory split is needed as a means to label the data. If the data is unlabelled (all `cats` & `dogs` images mixed together), it cannot evaluate the model correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I figured out recently and I've made corrections. However, my predictions aren't sequential and I can't remember shuffling the data. Is that normal?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly, but there's no need to shuffle the testing data. When evaluating a model its weights aren't updated, so any order the data is inputted should yield the same results. As for training/validation data, this does have an effect since the model is being updated when it's fitted.

Comment: The order of the test data is not maintained. I didn't shuffle it

Comment: The data is read in ascending alphanumeric order by the file name. However, the order of the data in the test set shouldn't matter anyway.